# Adding and Subtracting secs, mins and hours from two time-inputs

Tags: java, oop, subtraction

First I'd like to say that I'm not looking for someone to just hand me the whole program wrapped up in a box with a nice bow.  I'm honestly trying to understand and learn.  My assignment is to ask the user for two inputs of time in the format: hours, minutes, and seconds.  I then take those times and add them together or subtract one from the other. It is expected that time 1 is >= time 2. I'm not allowed to convert all time down to seconds and then convert it back either.  I'm also not allowed to use loops or if statements.  I did my addition already but it's the subtraction that I'm stuck at.  This is the bit I have for the addition:

```
Time addTime(Time t1, Time t2) {
    int h, m, s, cm, ch;
    s = (t1.s + t2.s)%60;
    cm = (t1.s + t2.s)/60;
    m = ((t1.m + t2.m) + cm)%60;
    ch = ((t1.m + t2.m) + cm)/60;
    h = (t1.h + t2.h) + ch;

    return new Time(h,m,s);
```

Now I need to take away (ex. (1h, 10m, 50s) - (0h, 0m, 75s) = (1h, 9m, 35s)) and I'm just not seeing how to do it with the limitations, though admittedly I'm really new to this and still have so much yet to learn.  If anyone could assist me or just point me in the right direction for doing the subtraction I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: *I'm not looking for someone to just hand me the whole program wrapped up in a box with a nice bow*, honestly! Adding and Subtracting is not called a project.

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to use "75s" as in the example?

Comment: Yes, time 2 can subtract a greater number of seconds and minutes than time 1 but the hours of time 2 can't be greater than the hours of time 1 or it will go into negative.

Comment: What class is `Time`?  Please [edit] your post and include the source for `Time`.

Comment: _"I'm just not seeing how to do it with the limitations"_ -- Suggested approach.   Add/subtract the `h`, `m`, `s` values first to produce potentially "de-normalized" values.  THEN go back and re-normalize them in the order seconds, minutes, hours.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I realize that figuring this out may be super easy to you and others but I've just started my coding journey so for me this is a challenge due to the limitations and my lack of know-how.  It may not be a project but I didn't really claim it to be.  This is a class assignment and I didn't want to appear as though I just wanted the answers handed to me. I meant no disrespect to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You generally have the right approach, but are confused because you are trying to do two different things simultaneously.  I suggest you do the arithmetic first, without paying attention to whether or not the result hour, minute and seconds fields are "normalized", and then normalize them.

So for your example

```
  01 : 10 : 50
- 00 : 00 : 75
```

Do the subtraction first, giving

```
  01 : 10 : -25
```

and then do the normalization to bring the values back into their proper ranges, dealing with the carry at that point.

Note that you are correctly using modulo (`%`) and integer division, but pay special attention to how `%` behaves with negative numbers. Refer to the language reference to be sure you understand it.